# Cannot ResolveFragmentTransaction.add() with v4.app.Fragment import

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to dynamically create a fragment and am getting the following error message:

> Cannot resolve method 'add(int, com.brewguide.android.coffeebrewguide.RecipeFragment)

Other answers I have looked up suggested that the library import for the fragment was off, so I've added the library imports `v4.app.Fragment` instead of  `app.Fragment` to both the Fragment and the Activity that calls the fragment and the issue hasn't gone away. Below is my code:

**MenuActivity.java**

```
package com.brewguide.android.coffeebrewguide;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int position;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //retrieves intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        //fetches menu option that was selected.
        // 0  is the default
        position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        // get an instance of FragmentTransaction from your Activity
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        //add a fragment
        RecipeFragment myFragment = new RecipeFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        switch (position){
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            default:
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                        "An Error has occurred.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                break;
        }
        if(getSupportActionBar()!= null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

}
```

**RecipeFragment.java**

```
package com.brewguide.android.coffeebrewguide;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class RecipeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_layout, container, false);
    }
    public RecipeFragment(){}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just the Fragment import... You also need the Support Fragments Manager instead of these

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

You need `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` when using the Support Fragments

Comment: Thank you! I switched to `getSupportGragmentManager()`, the library imports were slightly different: 
`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`
`import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;`